# Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module when trying to get jQuery maks plugin to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to user this plugin http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/, but I get the following error

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {
"use strict";
...rest of the code
```

Is this conflicting with jquery that's already loaded on the page? How can I fix this?

Here's how I am trying to use the plugin `$('input[type="tel"]').mask('(000) 000-0000');`

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote in order to use that plugin?

Comment: @taxicala, i updated my question

Comment: I need more code, how are you loading jquery script and mask script? are you running your code on document ready?

Comment: That error message apparently comes from `require.js`. Are you using that in your code? http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch